BladeRF Setup: Srsenb Tx and Rx always 0
After building srsLTE from source referring from this article(https://hernan.de/blog/creating-a-cellular-testbed-with-yatebts-and-srslte/).When we run srsepc and srsenb the Tx and Rx values are always set to 0.
Output of values while running srsenb and srsepc.
Trying to setup RogueBTS LTE to sniff traffic
